# Why does Brew's recommended installation use Ruby to call curl?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

In the [Brew installation guide](http://brew.sh), it says to run the following:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Why is Ruby being used? Couldn't everything before `curl` be excluded (and the matching close quote and parenthesis on the end too)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not using Ruby to call `curl`, that's calling `curl` directly, using command substitution in Bash to fetch the contents of the URL and then execute that as Ruby code. You can verify that by running:

```
echo "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This will print the Ruby code that is being executed using `ruby -e` in the original command.